Comment edit rejected too soon?
My comment was labeled as three minutes old when I clicked edit and added a few words.  "Comments can only be edited for five minutes" popped up.
I thought, well maybe three was correct when the page first loaded.  But when I dismissed the warning, the comment was labeled only four minutes old.
(I don't see the benefit of the rule.  Copy the comment with the unsaved edit still there, delete, and paste the edited text into a new comment—a trivial way to break the rule.)
I might add that the parenthetical is just that, and not part of the might-be-a-bug observation.

TL;DR: Broken as designed.
That is how Stack Exchange has decided it wants the system to work. There isn't anything that we can do about it as a single stack, and they have rejected suggestions that they change it at the system level.
Their argument seems to be that permitting edits to comments would risk people changing their comments so much that subsequent comments are invalidated. The fact that the same thing can happen with questions, and with answers, does not convince them that this can be managed. Apparently they had specific incidents of people changing comments in ways that made other comments look foolish, or something of that sort, and have settled on limiting editing as a way to prevent that, at the cost of not letting us fix typos or foolishness in our own comments.
The workaround is to copy the text into a new comment, edit it there, post it, and delete the old comment. This has the side effect of costing you any up-ticks the comment might already have acquired, and of moving your comment out of sequence and breaking the comment flow, but it is the only mechanism for editing older comments that the folks running Stack Exchange want to support.
Or post a new comment, saying oops and correcting your statement. Which maintains their sacred sequential flow, though it is of course awkward.
Drives me crazy too. But we're stuck with it.

(The 3 minutes versus 4 minutes versus 5 minutes thing it's probably a matter of exactly what clock is being referenced. I don't know whether they are operating on difference in milliseconds, difference in seconds, or difference in minutes; the choice of comparison will affect when the system thinks the threshold has been crossed, and it may be different from what your local clock thinks, never mind your local clock versus their system clock. Basically, expect rounding error. It's still "correct" behavior as SE has defined correct,  and still nothing that this stack can independently change.)

But the apparent glitch is that their clock went from three to five and then backward to four.

Nothing we can do about it in any case.
